# data not match with response from axios vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

im new in vuejs

I have button to get detail data like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" title="Detail" @click="showDetail(task.id)"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></button>
```

and the script like this

```
export default {
data(){
    return {
        tasks: [],
        taskDetail: [],
        categoryName: "",
        typeName: "",
        detailExist: false
    }
},
created(){
    this.getTasks()
},
methods: {
    getTasks(){
        axios.get("/task-lists/")
            .then(res => {
                this.tasks = res.data.data
            })
    },
    showDetail(id){
        
        this.detailExist = false
        axios.get("/task-detail/"+id)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                this.taskDetail = res.data.data
                this.detailExist = true
                this.collectCategory(this.taskDetail.category)
                this.collectType(this.taskDetail.type)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    },
    startTask(id){
        axios.post('/start-task', {id: id, status: 1})
            .then(res => {
                this.getTasks()
                console.log(res.data)
            })
    },
    finishDev(id){
        axios.post('/finish-dev', {id: id, status: 2})
            .then(res => {
                this.getTasks()
            })
    },
    collectCategory(val){
        switch (val) {
            case 2:
                this.categoryName = 'Normal';
                break;
            case 3:
                this.categoryName = 'Emergency';
                break;
        
            default:
                this.categoryName = 'Standard';
                break;
        }
    },
    collectType(val){
        switch (val) {
            case 2:
                this.typeName = 'New Feature';
                break;
            case 3:
                this.typeName = 'Bug Fixing';
                break;
        
            default:
                this.typeName = 'Revamp';
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

But i got confuse because there is a difference between what i get in res in axios and response api if i see from browser > inspect > network. In browser i get like this

```
{
"data": {
    "id": 1,
    "task_no": "RFC123XYZ",
    "task_name": "Task View",
    "mandays": 2,
    "start_date": "2021-10-12",
    "status": 2,
    "category": 2,
    "type": 2,
    "description": null,
    "cycle": [],
}
```

}

but in axios i always get value 1 in "status" when i console.log(res).

Comment: If this is your output from network analysis, can you please add the output from `console.log` of the same object?

Comment: {
    "id": 1,
    "task_no": "RFC123XYZ",
    "task_name": "Task View",
    "mandays": 2,
    "start_date": "2021-10-12",
    "status": 1,
    "category": 2,
    "type": 2,
    "description": null,
    "cycle": []
}

Comment: There has to be something in your code that modifies your data, it doesn´t change on it´s own. You call `"/task-detail/"+id` so it would be like `/task-detail/1`?

Comment: Ohh.. Thanks bro, ur right.. there are something that modify my data.. I have button with v-if="taskDetail.status = 1". It should be v-if="taskDetail.status == 1". Thank you for your help bro